# Error: 'Unsupported document-format "application/pdf"'

Tags: printing, pdf

I'm trying to print .pdf documents from the command line using the `lpr` command and I'm getting this error:

```
Unsupported document-format "application/pdf"
```

Could you please help me what can be the issue? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and CUPS 2.27

Comment: Have you tried pdf2ps?

Comment: What do you mean? Transform the pdf to ps then print it?

Comment: Yes, it's done on many occasions, and certainly no formatting would be lost anyway.

Comment: CUPS v2.27 does not exist. Do you mean v2.2.7?

Comment: This issue occurred on my system when upgrading from cups v2.4.6 to v2.4.7.  Downgrading back to v2.4.6 allows me to print pdf files using `lpr` as before.

Comment: In my case, it turns out my package manager no longer had the package `cups-filters` listed as a dependency of the `cups` package.  Installing the former explicitly brought back the desired functionality: print a pdf file using `lpr`.  It can be found here: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/cups-filters

Answer (score 2):

This could mean two things:

1. CUPS does not know how to convert incoming PDF documents to the final format your printer (*What printer model is it at all??? Troubleshooting stuff like this and trying to help you out is not easy if you are so tight-lipped...*) wants.

   - You should check if you have installed the *`cups-filters`* package: ***`dpkg -l cups*`***.
   - If it is missing, install it: ***`sudo apt-get install cups-filters`***
2. CUPS does not have an entry (or a commented out entry) naming *`application/pdf`* as one of the formats allowed for print submission, and/or does not have a ruleset to allow for auto-detection of this format -- but yet some print client explicitly told CUPS that it is wanting to send *`application/pdf`*.

   - Check if the following entry is in */usr/share/cups/mime.types*:

     ```
     application/pdf
     ```
   - Check if above entry also has the second field like in the following line:

     ```
     application/pdf                 pdf regex(0,^[\n\r]*%PDF)
     ```

Comment: what does it mean if i have CUPS installed but there is no `/usr/share/cups/mime.types'?

Comment: In my case it is in `/usr/share/cups/mime/mime.types`.

Answer (score -1):

In settings, search for printers and select appropriate drivers under printer details, then select from database.